# Validating e-mail address

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate an e-mail address using javascript. The problem is the if statements aren't executing correctly. If I delete the 'else statement' the code runs correnctly and the page does not load with errors. If I include the 'else statement' the else statement never executes and the status bar says that the page loads with errors. I was wondering if anyone can find any errors that I am unable to pick up?

```
<h4>Example 4:</h4>
<div style="border:3px dashed #aaa; width:200px;">
    <div id="text">e-mail: <input id="email" onblur="verifyEmail()"/></div>
    <div id="verification" > </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function verifyEmail(){
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var atPos=0;
     var dotPos=0;

    atPos = email.indexOf("@");
    dotPos = email.lastIndexOf(".");

    if(atPos<=3 || dotPos<atPos+2 || dotPos+2>=email.length){
        document.getElementById("verification").innerHTML = "Invalid E-mail Address";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("verification").innerHTML = "Valid";
    }

}



</script>
```

Comment: you should use a [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) to validate emails

Comment: e-mail validation can be done in javascript using code that is similar to the one above, and that was I an trying to do. I appreciate the response though.

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/9Hca5/

Comment: sure it CAN be done that way, but that doesn't mean it's done correctly. for instance, if i put in the email address `^$asd*(!)#*@*$9283.com`, it will validate using your system

Comment: also, you're saying that an email of `jas@abc@@@@.zz` is valid? and an email of `j@abc.com` isn't?

Comment: Your opinion whether or not my method is good to validate e-mails is besides the point that it is loading with errors and does not help answer my question. I got the basic email validation example above from w3schools.com, I am sure there are always better ways, but thats not what I was asking:) Please read the question first. thanks anyways.

Comment: w3schools is about the [worst place](http://w3fools.com/) you can get information about how things work on the internet. and it's not an opinion what i'm telling you. you are not doing anything to validate an email address other than making sure it has an @ symbol and a dot in it. that does not make an email valid. a valid email is a very complex thing to validate, as you can see by the myriad of very complex regexes that exist to try to accomplish this.

Comment: Here is what you should do: (i) search for some code examples on google (ii) click on a result from w3schools -- they usually appear at the top (iii) click your browsers back button (iv) on google search results page, click the link that says "block all results from w3schools.com"

Comment: Say what you will. w3schools is a one of the best starting points for beginners and covers a wide range of basics in a format that is easy to understand imo. Whether or not its examples should be applied to real websites, probably not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\
".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA
-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

**Demo** : [Here is the demo](http://jsbin.com/ozeyag/19)

OR a more simpler way is

```
function validateEmail(email) 
{
    var re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

if you are using HTML5 try `<input type="email"...` please note. this one works if the input is in a form tag with a submit button and isn't handled by JS

```
<input type="email" placeholder="me@example.com">
```

Comment: your last example only works if the input is in a form tag with a submit button and isn't handled by JS

Answer (score 2):

```
<script language="javascript">
function checkEmail() {
var email = document.getElementById('emailaddress');
var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
alert('Please provide a valid email address');
email.focus;
return false;
}
}
</script>
```

Read more: http://www.marketingtechblog.com/javascript-regex-emailaddress/#ixzz1wqetPJQQ